# Quotient of $\textrm{GL}(2,\textbf{R})$ by the conjugate action of $\textrm{SL}(2,\textbf{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, manifolds

I do not know if this is the right place to ask the following question. If it is not, I will delete it. I asked a similar question in math stack exchange and get a nice answer by @YCor.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924189/quotient-of-textrmgl2-textbfr-by-the-conjugate-action-of-textrmso

Let $\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{R})$ act on $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})$ by conjugation. Does the quotient $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})/\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{R})$ exist as a manifold?

I thank @ThiKu for his nice answer in this case.

Comment: The question for $SO(2)$ is now answered in MathSE (link above)

Comment: @YCor Thanks for your nice answer, which makes me think whether I should delete this post. But since I accept and answer, it seems that I cannot delete this one.

Comment: One option would be that you edit to only leave the question about quotient by $SL_2$, and that enough people vote to move it to MathSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By the Jordan normal form theorem every matrix in $GL(2,{\bf R})$ is conjugate to

- either a diagonal matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda_1&0\\
  0&\lambda_2\end{array}\right)$$ 
  (clearly the set of these classes is homeomorphic to $({\bf R}\setminus 0)^2/({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})$ with ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$ acting by permutation of the two coordinates.)
- or to a multiple of a triangular matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\pm 1&n\\
  0&\pm 1\end{array}\right)$$
- or to a multiple of a matrix in $SO(2)$.

However, the triangular matrices with eigenvalues $1$ are all in one of three orbits because of
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda_1&0\\
0&\lambda_1^{-1}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&n\\
0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda_1^{-1}&0\\
0&\lambda_1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&\lambda_1^2n\\
0&1\end{array}\right).$$
The three orbits correspond to the cases $n>0, n=0, n<0$. Note that the orbits for $n>0$ and $n<0$ can not be separated from the identity matrix (the case $n=0$) by any open neighborhood of the identity, because $\lambda_1^2n$ tends to zero for a suitable sequence of $\lambda_1$'s.

So the quotient space is non-Hausdorff, it contains of a copy of $({\bf R}\setminus 0)^2/({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})$ and another two points which can not be separated from $(1,1)$.

Comment: I am sorry. I cannot understand some points. For example, how do you get every matrix in $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})$ is conjugate to the given form under the conjugation by $\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{R})$? I don't know how to prove this even under the conjugation action of $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})$ because $\textbf{R}$ is not algebraically closed. In your second point, you showed that all the unipotent matrices are in the same orbit under the action of $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})$, but for $\textbf{SL_2}(\textbf{R})$-conjugacy class, I guess it's different.

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference whether you conjugate by GL(2,R) or SL(2,R) because every matrix in GL^+(2,R) is a multiple of a matrix in SL(2,R), and conjugation by a multiple of the identity acts trivially. So the only difference is that you have an additional Z/2Z-action coming from matrices with negative determinant. In any case, I have now edited the answer to consider only the SL(2,R)-action.

Comment: I am sorry. I am still confused at some points. What do you mean by "every matrix in $\textrm{GL}_2(\textbf{R})$" is a multiple of a matrix in $\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{R})$? For example, how do you write diag(-1,1) as "a multiple of a matrix in $\textrm{SL}_2(\textbf{R})$?

Comment: For the normal form: I kind of ignore matrices with non-real eigenvalues because already those with real eigenvalues yield a non-Hausdorff space, so the same must be true for the larger space.

Comment: For your last question: I meant matrices in GL^+(2,R), i.e., those with positive determinant.

Comment: Thanks. So your argument showed that $G_0/SL_2(\textbf{R})$ is non-Hausdorff where $G_0$ is the subset of $GL_2^+(R)$ which consists matrices $g$ such that $g$ has two real eigenvalues.

Comment: If I change the group $SL_2(R)$ to $SO_2(R)$, it seems that the quotient space $GL_2(R)/SO_2(R)$ is automatically Hausdorff since $SO_2(R)$ is compact. I would like to know if the quotient has a manifold structure.

Comment: How do you deal with size 2 Jordan blocks whose diagonal entries aren't equal to 1?

Comment: They yield non-Hausdorff points in the quotient, for the same reason: their orbit accumulates at the diagonal matrix.

Comment: Okay, it just seems that the claim in the beginning of your answer is missing that case.